# Does Kotlin support OptionSet?

Tags: kotlin

In `Swift` programming language an `[OptionSet]`[1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) is a modern interface on top of a `bitset` and it's used to define a set of options without dealing with low-level bitwise operation

The swift syntax is

```
let multipleOptions: ShippingOptions = [.nextDay, .secondDay, .priority]
```

Does Kotlin offers something similar? I know Kotlin has the `BitSet`[2](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native/-bit-set/) but I'm looking for something more readable.

So far the best solution I have found is a `Set<SomeEnum>`.

Comment: No. You should write sealed class implementation of it or just use enums.

Comment: thanks @NikolaDespotoski enums alone will not do the trick, as enum can have one single value. A `Set` of enum is the closes solution I have found

Comment: hai.  i m facing similar issue. can you please help me me